# Conjecture on digits in arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions, perfect-powers

Let $n\geq 100$ be some positive integer in base $10$. Take its consecutive digits in groups of $k$ digits each. I have the following

**Conjecture:** *If the digits of some positive integer $n\geq 100$ in base 10, taken consecutively in groups of $k$ digits each, form an increasing or decreasing arithmetic progression of three or more elements, then $n$ is neither a prime number nor a perfect power.*

For instance, $125$ is a perfect power, but $1,2,5$ do not form an arithmetic progression. $1,2,3,4$ form an increasing arithmetic progression, but $1234$ is neither a prime nor a perfect power.

I have verified the conjecture for all three-digits numbers (which only admit groups of $1$ digit each) and all four-digits numbers (which only admit groups of $1$ digit each, as groups of $2$ digits can not form an arithmetic progression of three or more elements).

I must admit that I am a bit lost about (i) how to check efficiently for numbers with a bigger number of digits, and (ii) why the conjecture could be true, apart from the scarcity argument of the sets that need to intersect to have a counterexample.

Any help on checking and / or proving / disproving the conjecture, or understanding better how to approach the problem, would be welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: $4567$ is a prime. So is $10987$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for your comment! I think that the number is $r + (10^k(r-a)) + \cdots + (10^{sk}(r-sa))$ instead of the one you have proposed (a parenthesis missed)

Comment: @EricSnyder last one doesn't work because it isn't $k$ digits at a time, but former one does.

Comment: It would seem that $1516171819$ is prime (taken 2 at a time).

Comment: Both $4567$ and $1516171819$ are valid counterexamples. Thanks!